# Add JavaScript to dynamic (plugin-generated) element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a plugin that I've downloaded that dynamically adds an element to the page upon clicking an image. I'm trying to add some JavaScript (`slideUp()`) to one of the newly added elements, but it's not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.image').imageClick({ 'fadeSpeed': 1000, 'targetHeight': 210 });
    $(".container").mouseover(function() {
        $(".overlay").hide().slideUp();
    });
</script>
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) will solve this for you:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.container', function() {
    $(".overlay").hide().slideUp();
});
```